# How can I save repeatable fields with one value inside an array?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, custom-field

**Introduce**
I am currently working on a slider plugin to learn a lot of PHP and WordPress.
I have create some repeatable field with javascript.

**Some functional details:**

- When the user is clicking on a button, the last row will cloned and
  all values will reset.
- Add an increase to the javascript code for create unique ids for my input names and id's.
- Add an unique id for my rows that are cloned.

**The problem:**
I wrote this topic, because I have some issues with saving values from one variable in an array.

When I save the post or page, the first field will overwritten. This is because I loop through one image and one caption, not through the `$_POST` variable.

**Question:**
My question now is how I can resolve this problem? I have also looked at the source code that @brasofilo has recommended at [Github - Gist](https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/4727349/). Brasofilo has only used one meta, but I would like to use a multidimensional array to create my fields. And save the values in one row in the database as an array.

I know that I can make use of several other plugins, but as I said before I would like to learn a lot of WordPress and PHP scripting language.

**Script PHP:**

> Here you can see my used code for now, as I said before, it only saves
>   one image and one caption.

```
<?php

// Add meta box support
// This registers a function to be called when the WordPress admin interface is visited
add_action("admin_init", "dsslider_manager_add_meta");
function dsslider_manager_add_meta(){

    // Create this cool new meta box for Portfolio Options
    add_meta_box("dsslider-meta", "Brandbox Options", "dsslider_manager_meta_options", "brandbox-slider", "normal", "high");
}

// Create the fields array
$prefix = 'dsmeta_';
$custom_meta_fields = array(
    array(
        'label' => 'Image',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'image',
        'type' => 'image',
        'repeatable' => true,
    ),
    array(
        'label' => 'Image caption',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'image_caption',
        'type' => 'text',
        'repeatable' => true,
    )
);

// Callback unctions for setting up Brandbox Options
function dsslider_manager_meta_options(){

    global $custom_meta_fields, $post;
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        // (integer) (optional) The post ID whose custom fields will be retrieved. 
        // Default: Current post
        return $post_id;

echo '<div class="dsslider_manager_extras">';

    // Markup for table head
    echo '<table class="meta ds-input-table">';
    echo '<tbody class="ui-sortable">';


    // Use nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="dsmeta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />';

    // Begin a table row
    echo '<tr class="row" id="repeatable-[0]">';
    echo '<td class="order">1</td>';

    foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {
        // Get value of this field if it exists for this post
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
        $type = $field['type'];

        // Each $meta in an table data
        echo '<td>';

        // Check if value repeatable is set
        if ($field['repeatable']) {

            switch ($type) {
                // Image case
                case 'image':

                    $image = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/default.jpg'; // Default image for the preview
                    echo '<span class="default_image" style="display:none">' . $image . '</span>';

                    // If $meta == (equal to) true
                    if ($meta) {
                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($meta, 'thumbnail');
                        $image = $image[0]; // Get the first key of the array - url
                    } // End if

                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . $field['id'] . '" class="upload_image" value="' . $meta . '" />'; // Save the image ID
                    echo '<img src="' . esc_attr( $image ) . '" alt="" class="preview_image" />'; // Preview uploaded image
                    echo '<input type="button" class="button add-image" value="Add image" rel="' . get_the_ID() . '" />'; // Add image
                    echo '<small><a href="#" class="remove-image">Remove image</a></small>'; // Delete image

                break;

                // Text case
                case 'text':
                    echo '<input type="text" name="' . $field['id'] . '[]' . '" id="' . $field['id'] . '" value="' . $meta . '" size="30" /> ';
                break;

            } // End switch statement

        } // End if

        echo '</td>';

    } // End foreach loop

    echo '<td class="remove"><a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">-</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>'; // End .row


    echo '</tbody>'; // End tbody
    echo '</table>'; // End tbody

    echo '<ul class="hl clearfix ds-repeater-footer"><li class="right">';
    echo '<a href="#" class="repeatable-add ds-button">Add New Slide</a>';
    echo '</li></ul>';

echo '</div>'; // End .dsslider_manager_extras
}

// Save the data
add_action('save_post', 'dsslider_manager_save_extras');
function dsslider_manager_save_extras($post_id) {

    global $custom_meta_fields;

    // Check autosave function
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    } // End if statement

    // Check permissions
    if ('page' == 'post_type') {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
        }
        elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    } // End if statement

    // Loop through fields and save the data  
    foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {
        if (isset($_POST[$field['id']])) {
            $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
            $new = $_POST[$field['id']];

            if ($new && $new != $old) {
                update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
            }
            elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
            }
        } // End if statement
    } // End foreach loop
}
```

Comment: Please, embed all relevant code in the Question itself. If those *snippi's* go off-line, the Q loses its meaning.

Comment: @brasofilo I have update it, give it some nice markup. Hope it's better now up to you!

Comment: +1 well written Q, kudos! That's not my code, just a fork with minor mods.

Comment: @brasofilo Thank you for your comment. Hope someone can help me out!

Comment: There's already an Answer, did you tried it? And if there are doubts, comment on it, I'm positive you'll get feedback.

Comment: @brasofilo, yes absolute I have tried the code bellow. But I think I am wrong with implement it into my own code. 

I have changed the name attribute to `<input name="text[]" />`. Also @david.binda used 'fields' inside the `$_POST` variable, but I have a different markup which I had no key value pair `'fields' => array()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are saving only one image and one image caption. Your loop in dsslider_manager_save_extras function loops throught global $custom_meta_fields defined in php file. Not through $_POST variable. Your loop should look something like this:

```
foreach ( $_POST['fields'] as $field ) {
...
}
```

In HTML, the form should look like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields[$field[ID]]" value=""/>
```

You can read more on this topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433727/submitting-a-multidimensional-array-via-post-with-php

Comment: Ok, I have tried several ways with the example above from @david.binda Because I haven't an key=>value pair of fields, I am stuck with the above answer code, as my code shown above, I make use of a multidimensional array and my metabox is separate from it.

Answer (score 1):

If your form looking something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="fields[0]['image']" value="" />
<input type="text" name="fields[0]['caption']" value="" />
```

And repeated by incrementing the index:

```
<input type="text" name="fields[1]['image']" value="" />
<input type="text" name="fields[1]['caption']" value="" />
```

Then what you'll get later is something like this:

```
$_POST['fields'] = array(
  0 => array(
    'image' => (value here)
    'caption' => (value here)
  ),
  1 => array(
    'image' => (value here)
    'caption' => (value here)
  )
);
```

Then in `save_post` you can check to see if:

```
isset($_POST['fields']) && is_array($_POST['fields']) && !empty($_POST['fields'])
```

Then you can loop through your `$custom_meta_fields` in a while loop:

```
$index = 0;
$slides = array();

while(isset($_POST['fields'][$index])) {
  foreach($custom_meta_fields as $custom_meta_field) {
    // check if isset($_POST['fields'][$index][$custom_meta_fields['id']])
    // and anything else you want to validate
    // and then save field in $slides[$index][$custom_meta_fields['id']]
  }
  $index++;
}
```

Once you've validated all sides, you can store them in one option field:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, $option_name, $slides);
```

By the way, in terms of $_POST['fields'], you could setup your array like so:

```
$custom_meta_fields = array(
    'slides' => array(
      array(
        'label' => 'Image',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'image',
        'type' => 'image',
        'repeatable' => true,
      ),
      array(
        'label' => 'Image caption',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'image_caption',
        'type' => 'text',
        'repeatable' => true,
      )
    )
);
```

Then you can still loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your expanded answer it is now for me a lot clearer. One question left for you now, in your array `$custom_meta_fields` you set the key **'slides'**. Why is this so important and I think I should replace **'fields'** in your example to 'slides' right? Look out to your answer, I will try your code today!

Comment: I came up to one more question while I try to implement your example code in mine code. The line `update_post_meta($post_id, $option_name, $slides);` you set a var of `$option_name` what should that variable does?

Comment: I have also take a better look to my own code that I have post in my Question. When I check my database I see that my caption is saved as an array with multiple values that I've insert in the text input fields, but doesn't show after save the post/page in WordPress, only the word **"Array"** will filled in then. Maybe you have something on this information..

Comment: For now I came up with the following code, after follow your example: http://snippi.com/s/jlzd2ju But this will give me a notice error: `Notice: Undefined variable: index in cpt-manager.php on line 187`

Comment: Yes, you should replace `fields` with something more descriptive, such as `slides`, but I'd make it more unique in case someone or something else ever uses `slides`. `$option_name` would be any string, also as unique as possible, that you'd use to save/retrieve the contents of your array from the database. `get_post_meta` returns an array of custom fields (in case you have more than one) and unless you specify true as the third argument e.g. `$slides = get_post_meta($post_id, $option_name, true)`, you'll have to supply the index e.g. `$slides[0]`.

Comment: Ok, so on I should replace `fields` for a more unique name, in our case for the array as well as the field name attribute. For now, it's just not entirely clear what exactly I with the `$option_name` should do. I understand only that we want save multiple strings. Also as you probably already read above, I can use my old code values ​​to store in the database are stored as an array, only after saving, only the default row with textInput **"Array"** on.

Comment: `$option_name` could be a string like `slides`... it's just a key in the database to retrieve your options i.e. array of slides. In terms of `Array`, you're trying to print an array as a string, but it's an array. Whatever your variable is called that prints `Array`, try this: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($your_variable, true) . '</pre>'` and you'll see exactly what the array contains. Then you can grab the appropriate string via the index.

Comment: Thank you for fast respond. So `$option_name` is a variable that contains a string like: `$option_name = "slides";` ? And then inside the database the array will look like this: `a:5:{i:0;a:1:{s:4:"slides";s:5:"Caption 1";}i:1;a:1:{s:4:"slides";s:8:"Caption 2";}i:2;a:1:{s:4:"slides";s:7:"Caption 2";}}` I think.. Should I copy/past the echo inside my save function or? Sorry for asking these questions, but I am not a pro in PHP. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Yes in terms of `$option_name`. The serialized array you printed though, does not seem to contain the image ID, just the caption. I don't know what your specific needs are, but I would assume the array would look much like the array I posted above (`$_POST['fields']`) when stored in the database, in terms of structure i.e. array of image ID/caption pairs.

Comment: Yes I will definitely take your advice. The intention is that I ultimately for each slide image and the corresponding caption can retrieve. Currently I'm still working on your code, just come here so far not continue, but not came up with a working one.. :(

Comment: Ah, okay now I understand more and more the operation behind `$ option_name`. I have the value **"dsmeta"** linked to the variable, then a entered a value in my input and saved the post / page. When I look in my database it says in the column **"meta_key"** the value **"dsmeta"**. I go further with try out your code, I let you know if I get it work tomorrow! For now many thanks for your time and effort to help me, hopefully we get it together work and is my plugin ready to be used!